# Virtual environment and django is not created in my directory. Python 3.11

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

```
PS C:\Users\38099\Desktop\courses> pipenv install django==4.0.8
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: C:\Users\38099\Pipfile
Using C:/Users/38099/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe (3.11.1) to create virtualenv...
[    ] Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.11.1.final.0-64 in 501ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\38099\.virtualenvs\38099-inBhiGOL, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\38099\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==23.0, setuptools==67.1.0, wheel==0.38.4
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\38099\.virtualenvs\38099-inBhiGOL
Installing django==4.0.8...
Resolving django==4.0.8...
Installing...
Adding django to Pipfile's [packages] ...
Installation Succeeded
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (664a36)...
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

I need to install virtual environment and *Django* version in my directory `C:\Users\38099\Desktop\courses>`. But every time the location of virtual environment is `C:\Users\38099\.virtualenvs\38099-inBhiGOL`. *Pipenv* in my *Powershell* is installed. I also have folder `.venv` in my explorer, but it ignores it anyway, choosing different location.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your virtualenv to be created in your project folder, and not in the default `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/` folder, set the environment variable `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` to `1` (`export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1` in your terminal).

[See the pipenv doc](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv.environments.Setting.PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT)